# .htaccess code to make urls lowercase and to add trailing slash when needed adds an extra trailing slash on occasion. Any ideas how to fix it?

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a simple website with two pages that have the following URLs:

- http://www.gulfcoastgetaway.org/donate/
- http://www.gulfcoastgetaway.org/questions/

I have an .htaccess file that I've pieced together to make sure that a trailing slash is added (/donate => /donate/) and also to make things lowercase (/Donate => /donate/).

But a url that has a capital letter and has a trailing slash (/DOnate/) gets rewritten with extra trailing slashes (one extra one per character that gets transformed to lowercase). So /Donate/ => /donate//  and /DONate/ => /donate////

I don't really know how to fix this, as my familiarity with .htaccess is limited.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

As I said, I need it to not add those extra trailing slashes.

Comment: You really should learn about the internal functions: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int

Comment: The specific issue you have is that you forgot the `[L]` flag in your rules ment to convert characters to lower case. That means that the last rule in the file will get applied _each time_ you convert a character to lower case.